# Wix populate listbox

Tags: listbox, wix

I am trying to fill in a ListBox with CustomAction and it's not going well.
I try to figure out the `session.Database.Tables` but have no idea how to start.

I've created a listbox like this

```
<Control Id="ListBox1" Type="ListBox" Sorted="no"  Indirect="no" Property="LISTBOXVALUESONE" X="10" Y="50" Width="150" Height="180">
      <ListBox Property="LISTBOXVALUESONE">
        <ListItem Text="ARGHH!" Value="1"/>
      </ListBox>
    </Control>
```

But I cant see the property in my verbrose log or anything about an table so I guess I have to create an table in customAction and populate it?
I see my `ARGHH!` in the list so it should exsist but how do I access the values? And add new ones?

Found more examples and stuff in C++ but i would like to make the CustomAction in C#

EDIT

```
Database db = session.Database;
string sqlInsertTemp = db.Tables["ListBox"].SqlInsertString + " TEMPORARY";
View view = db.OpenView(sqlInsertTemp );
view.Execute( new Record( new object[] { "LISTBOXVALUESONE", 2, "2", "One" } ));
view.Close();
```

Thanks to Christopher I got it to work with adding an value.

`db.Tables["ListBox"]` should remain the same and name the type not the id as i taught
And on this line `view.Execute( new Record( new object[] { "LISTBOXVALUESONE", 2, "2", "One" } ));`
you put your Listbox Property and then the placement of the value "one" we insert

The two "2"s is what I figure the placement we want it on and I already have an test value on 1
my "ARGHH!" so I put the new on 2 and dont know the details but...

I got an Table Update error and, one dublicate value error if i put 2,1 or 1,2 in the customaction!

Comment: Dynamically emitting rows in MSI is a powerful concept but bewarned that you lose the benefits of validation at build time. Therefore you must make sure that the rows you insert are 100% valid.

Comment: @ChristopherPainter Valid characters for XML you mean? luckily i read in foldernames and they cant be named with anything you want :)

Comment: The XML is used to create Windows Installer tables. It's the table data that I'm talking about. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa369554%28v=vs.85%29.aspx http://blog.iswix.com/2009/02/msi-tip-authoring-ice-using-c-dtf.html

Answer (score 3):

I wrote a blog article about 5 years ago that might help you:

[How DTF is going to help me become a better .NET Developer](http://blog.iswix.com/2008/05/how-dtf-is-going-to-help-me-become.html)

You want to make sure your built MSI has a ListBox table otherwise the SQL won't work when it tries to generate the temp rows dynamically at runtime.  If the ListBox element doesn't do this for you, the EnsureTable element will.

The actual C# looks something like:

```
Database db = session.Database;
string sqlInsertTemp = db.Tables["ListBox"].SqlInsertString + " TEMPORARY";
View view = db.OpenView(sqlInsertTemp );
view.Execute( new Record( new object[] { "TESTPROP", 1, "1", "One" } ));
view.Close();
```

Note this is an old code example and doesn't properly take advantage of using statements and IDisposable.

Comment: Thank you Christopher :) got it to work in adding an value if anyone else wonders about the "TESTPROP", 1, "1", "One" line i tested some variations look in my edit!

Comment: I assumed you'd understand the values were just sample data and not intended for your situation.  It was written 5 years ago.  If you look at MSDN (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa369762%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)  you'll see that the primary key is on the first two columns.  Each Row/Order must be unique.

Comment: yea thank you :) i understand it all much better now. this link was also very helpful (http://blog.torresdal.net/2008/10/24/wix-and-dtf-using-a-custom-action-to-list-available-web-sites-on-iis/)

Answer (score 0):

Add one record to list box:

```
private void AddRecordToListBox(string listBoxPropertyName, int index, string text, string value)
{
    View view = session.Database.OpenView("SELECT * FROM ListBox");
    view.Execute();

    Record record = session.Database.CreateRecord(4);

    record.SetString(1, listBoxPropertyName);
    record.SetInteger(2, index);
    record.SetString(3, value);
    record.SetString(4, text);

    view.Modify(ViewModifyMode.InsertTemporary, record);
    view.Close();
}
```

Fill ListBox:

```
private void FillListBox()
{
    var dict = SomeDict();

    int index = 1;
    foreach (var element in dict)
    {
        AddRecordToListBox(ListBoxName, index, element.Key, element.Value);
        index++;
    }
}
```

Clear ListBox

```
private void ClearListBox(string listBoxPropertyName)
{
    var command = String.Format("DELETE FROM ListBox WHERE ListBox.Property='{0}'", listBoxPropertyName);
    View view = session.Database.OpenView(command);
    view.Execute();
    view.Close();
}
```